# Need some help implementing collisions in my game, with two separate classes

Tags: c#, xna

What I'm trying to do is to draw rectangles behind the background and make essentially collision detection. What I'm not sure however is how exactly I can implement that. I thought about making it so that as the sprite approached these rectangles, their speed would get slower and slower till they stop but would that work? Sorry if I sound a bit wet behind the ears, I'm fairly new to C# and am trying to self teach. Any help would be appreciated.

So I have a CharacterSprite class (walkingsprite) all the stuff about the frames is just a walking animation sequence I implemented.

```
namespace walkingsprite
{
class AnimatedSprite
{
    //keyboard
    KeyboardState currentKBState;
    KeyboardState previousKBState;

    Texture2D spriteTexture;

    float timer = 0f;
    float interval = 200f;
    int currentFrame = 0;
    int spriteWidth = 32;
    int spriteHeight = 48;
    int spriteSpeed = 2;

    Rectangle sourceRect;

    Texture2D obst;
    Rectangle obst1;

    Obstruction obstruction1;


    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 origin;


    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }

    public Vector2 Origin
    {
        get { return origin; }
        set { origin = value; }
    }

    public Texture2D Texture
    {
        get { return spriteTexture; }
        set { spriteTexture = value; }
    }

    public Rectangle SourceRect
    {
        get { return sourceRect; }
        set { sourceRect = value; }
    }

    public int SpriteSpeed
    {
        get { return spriteSpeed; }
        set { spriteSpeed = value; }
    }

    public AnimatedSprite(Texture2D texture, int currentFrame, int spriteWidth, int spriteHeight)
    {
        this.spriteTexture = texture;
        this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
        this.spriteWidth = spriteWidth;
        this.spriteHeight = spriteHeight;
    }

    public void HandleSpriteMovement(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        previousKBState = currentKBState;
        currentKBState = Keyboard.GetState();

        sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);



        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (currentKBState.GetPressedKeys().Length == 0)
        {
            if (currentFrame > 0 && currentFrame < 4)
            {
                currentFrame = 0;
            }

            if (currentFrame > 4 && currentFrame < 8)
            {
                currentFrame = 4;
            }

            if (currentFrame > 8 && currentFrame < 12)
            {
                currentFrame = 8;
            }

            if (currentFrame > 12 && currentFrame < 16)
            {
                currentFrame = 12;
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //sprintin
        if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            spriteSpeed = 2;
            interval = 100;
        }
        else 
        {
            spriteSpeed = 1;
            interval = 200;
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////


        if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) == true)
        {
            AnimateDown(gameTime);
            if (position.Y < 575)
            {
                position.Y += spriteSpeed;
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) == true)
        {
            AnimateUp(gameTime);
            if (position.Y > 25)
            {
                position.Y -= spriteSpeed;
            }
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
        {
            AnimateRight(gameTime);
            if (position.X < 780)
            {
                position.X += spriteSpeed;
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (currentKBState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
        {
            AnimateLeft(gameTime);
            if (position.X > 0)
            {
                position.X -= spriteSpeed;

            }
        }
        origin = new Vector2(sourceRect.Width / 2, sourceRect.Height / 2);

    }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    public void AnimateRight(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (currentKBState != previousKBState)
        {
            currentFrame = 9;
        }

        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if(timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if(currentFrame > 11)
            {
                currentFrame = 8;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }

    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void AnimateUp(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (currentKBState != previousKBState)
        {
            currentFrame = 13;
        }
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if (currentFrame > 15)
            {
                currentFrame = 12;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    public void AnimateDown(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (currentKBState != previousKBState)
        {
            currentFrame = 1;
        }
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if (currentFrame > 3)
            {
                currentFrame = 0;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       public void AnimateLeft(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (currentKBState != previousKBState)
        {
            currentFrame = 5;
        }
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;

            if (currentFrame > 7)
            {
                currentFrame = 4;
            }
            timer = 0f;
        }
    }
  }
   }
```

And I have an obstruction class.

```
 namespace walkingsprite
 {
class Obstruction
{
    Texture2D obst;
    Rectangle obstRec1;

    public Rectangle ObstRec1
    {
        get { return obstRec1; }
        set { obstRec1 = value; }
    }

    public Texture2D Obst
    {
        get { return obst; }
        set { obst = value; }
    }

    public Obstruction(Texture2D texture, Rectangle rec)
    {
        this.obstRec1 = rec;
        this.obst = texture;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You should use Box2D!

Answer (score 0):

XNA already have a `Rectangle` class with a method to return if a rectangle collide with another rectangle.

An exemple:

```
Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10);
rec1.Intersects(rec2); //Return true if a rectangle intersects another one
```

What people normally do, is a `List` of `Rectangle` and test one by one to know if they collide, or they implements a [`QuadTree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) but that is a bit more difficult in the beginning.

An exemple of a `List` of `Rectangle`:

```
List<Rectangle> allObjects = new List<Rectangle>();
Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(10, 15, 10, 10);
Rectangle mainCharRec = new Rectangle(10, 20, 10, 10);

allObjects.Add(rec1);
allObjects.Add(rec2);
```

To test if main character rectangle intersects some other rectangles you can do a method with a foreach like this:

```
foreach (Rectangle rec in allObjects)
     if(mainCharRec.Intersects(rec))
          return true;
return false;
```

About getting slower, I think you could have a rectangle to the object and another to the "close region", and when the character enter in the region you slow his speed by the distance you give to the region, for example, if you have a rectangle with 10 pixels larger for each side, when character collides with larger rectangle he loses spriteSpeed/10 for step, until he stops. When the value is too much low, it turn 0:

```
if (spriteSpeed < 0.5)
     spriteSpeed = 0;
else
    spriteSpeed -= spriteSpeed/10;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the help. So if the Intersect method returned true, should I do the spriteSpeed lowering?

Comment: yes, if you receive true, you can begin to slow the character

Comment: how would the character move back then? the speed would be 0

Comment: When the character change the direction you can back his speed to 1 or 2.